# Timer for functions with any parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, delegates, coroutine

I'm working with unity, but in this instance it's just a c# question. Is there a way to make a timer that will run any function, with any parameters? I've been using delegates to put a function into either a timer class or coroutine, but I can't figure out how to put any parameters into the delegate.

Also, there are many questions like mine, but the difference (since I couldn't find any addressing specifically what I'm asking) is that I want to be able to run a function, any function I want, no matter what parameters it may or may not need, after a specified amount of seconds have passed. Essentially I want to be able to run a coroutine that takes float time and a delegate function. It waits for time seconds, and then runs the delegate function. But then, I need to be able to put in parameters for the function if it needs it, so if I want to run a simple function that does

Debug.Log(comment)

after taking comment as a string parameter, or

Debug.Log(number)

after taking number as a float parameter.

So to sum up, how can I wait for x seconds to perform function y, and change what y is to whatever I want without having to create a new set of delegates and functions?

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, or easily accessible information, as I've been unable to find anything answering it after about an hour of searching.

Comment: `Debug.Log()` works because it takes one parameter: an object. And everything in C# is an object. Is that what you're looking for? Or maybe you're looking for Generic types? `Func<T,U>`, etc?

Comment: Making the inputs objects would work if the parameter amount stays the same, but what if I wanted to do Debug.Log(comment + number) afterward, with two parameters? Is there some way I could make the delegate take anywhere from 0 to 100 parameters, all of which being objects?

Comment: @HackerMan, yes, it's [possible](https://www.dotnetperls.com/params). The problem is in your case you must pass array of objects and then check every element's type then cast and then finally do what you want to do. Are you sure that writting function which can do anything with anything is what you need?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you can use `Timer`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.6

Comment: Did you also try [this one](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1232680/view.html)? It seems to able to handle parameters..

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to have as flexible a solution I wanted, but I got around it by creating a set of zero/one/two/etc. parameter delegates and coroutines, so if I want to wait 5 seconds to run a function called debugHello and put "hello" as a parameter for debugHello, I would put debugHello into a delegate instance of oneParamMeth called debugHelloMeth and then do StartCoroutine(oneParamMethTimer(5, debugHellometh, "hello")); . This way, at least with void functions, I can do as many parameters as I like as long as I make a new pair of delegate and coroutine to go with them.

EDIT: DerHugo's comment works much better! A lot cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use lambda functions.

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine(float delay, System.Action action)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    action();
}
```

and then

```
float number = 1.0f;
string comment;
StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(0.5f, () =>
    {
        Debug.Log(number);
        Debug.Log(comment);
    });

Vector3 tmp = Vector3.zero;
StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(1.0f, () =>
    {
        transform.position = tmp;
    });
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with an existing function, so that every time this is called it wouldn't be necessary to write out the function's code?

Comment: You should then modify your function to generic one. Check out [this (second paragraph, but first one might resolve your problem as well).](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/generic-methods-in-c/)